# tkinter - how to run a conditional statement on button press (user enters age and height), output sent to textbox

Tags: python, function, if-statement, tkinter, conditional-statements

Relatively new to tkinter so please be kind. I'm playing around with an exercise that gets a user to input their age and height. Based on the conditional it will output whether they can ride that particular attraction. The code below is not finished. I know I need to create a function for button press to run the IF statement (which is just placed at the bottom and not in the correct spot), but unsure on the code to use for this. I also believe I need to create two variables = to the data entered in each of the textboxes correct? (enterager and enterheight). Thanks :)

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Rollercoaster")

l0 = Label(window, text = "Can you ride the roller coaster?", bg="black", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman",14, "italic"))
l1 = Label(window, text = "Enter Age")
l2 = Label(window, text = "Enter Height")
l3 = Label(window, text = "Can you ride it?")

l0.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 2)
l1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 2)
l2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 2)
l3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 2)

output = Text(window, width=20, height=1, wrap=WORD, background="white")
output.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

enterage = Entry(window)
enterheight = Entry(window)

enterage.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 2)
enterheight.grid(row = 2, column = 1, pady = 2)

b1 = Button(window, text = "Submit")
b1.grid(row = 1, column = 2)


if age >=12 and height>=150:
    print("You are ready to ride")
else:
    print("You are too short, young or both")


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, I was running into this. I need to declare age as a variable = to the enterage textbox. How does one do this? Something like age = enterage ? That didn't work for me.

Comment: You need to get the input from the `Entry` widgets using `.get()`, for example `age = enterage.get()`, and convert them to integers (or float numbers).  Also you need to do the checking inside a function that is triggered by the button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.get()` on the `Entry` widgets to get the input values and convert them into integers.  Also you need to do the checking inside a function which is triggered by the submit button:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Rollercoaster")

l0 = Label(window, text = "Can you ride the roller coaster?", bg="black", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman",14, "italic"))
l1 = Label(window, text = "Enter Age")
l2 = Label(window, text = "Enter Height")
l3 = Label(window, text = "Can you ride it?")

l0.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 2)
l1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 2)
l2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 2)
l3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 2)

output = Text(window, width=30, height=2, wrap=WORD, background="white")
output.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

enterage = Entry(window)
enterheight = Entry(window)

enterage.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 2)
enterheight.grid(row = 2, column = 1, pady = 2)

# function called by clicking the submit button
def submit():
    try:
        # clear the result
        output.delete("1.0", "end")
        # get the input values for age and height
        age = int(enterage.get())
        height = int(enterheight.get())
        # perform checking and show the result
        if age >= 12 and height >= 150:
            output.insert("end", "You are ready to ride")
        else:
            output.insert("end", "You are too short, young or both")
    except:
        output.insert("end", "Need to input integer for age and height")

b1 = Button(window, text = "Submit", command=submit)
b1.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much. I got this to work beautifully! Cheers